# What does "Twist someone's arm" mean?

Tags: meaning

It means kinds of persuade or force somebody to do something ?
Could somebody explain this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that of forcing someone into doing something by metaphorically twisting their arm:

[twist someone’s arm:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/twist-someone-s-arm)
​

> to get someone to do what you want by making it very difficult for him or her to refuse:
>
> - I didn’t want to go to the exhibition, but Linda twisted my arm.

[image]

Comment: So , it is stronger than persuade ,right?

Comment: @libs_liu - I guess so.

Comment: It does not have to imply cruelty or unfairness. I didn't want to go to Uncle Joe's party, but my sister twisted my arm, and later I was glad she did.